# Directly installing file from internet with package manager instead of downloading it first (Lubuntu Disco Dingo 64)

Tags: software-installation

I just installed Google Chrome and chose to directly open/install the .deb file with the package manager instead of downloading it first. I am assuming this downloads the .deb file as a temp file somewhere?

Does this file automatically delete after the install? If not, where would it be located so I can delete it?

I looked in /var/cache/apt/archives and did not see it.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "directly open/install the .deb file." That *is* downloading. It's also not clear which package manager you are referring to.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What exactly did you do?

Comment: I assume that you clicked on "Open with" while downloading using Firefox. Firefox saves that in /tmp/mozilla_username0. As soon as browser closes it gets deleted

Comment: Yes, I was aware that I didn't mention *which* package manager. It happened so fast - flashed for less than a second - that I could not remember. I am pretty new to Linux so sometimes ask in roundabout ways. Apologies. I did use FFox but do not see /tmp/mozilla_username0 on my computer. I am using Lubuntu Disco Dingo (19.04). I am also new to this OS (installed May 20).

Comment: I just repeated the process as if I were going to install Chrome. It is Open with >> QApt Package Installer (default), using Firefox.

Comment: @earthpages replace username with your username. For me it's mozilla_kulfy0

Answer (score 0):

The .deb installer, in your usage scenario, is stored in `/tmp`.

The contents of the temporary folder are deleted during a reboot.